# Was bedeutet das Wort "Harmen"?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage

Bei der Übersetzung eines Gedichts von Klabund bin ich auf eine Zeile gestoßen, deren Bedeutung mir nicht ganz klar ist. Das Gedicht lautet wie folgt:

> **Der Friede**
>
> Der Friede stürzt ins Land
> Gleich einem Schaf, von Wölfen angerissen.
> Er trägt ein grau Gewand,
> Zerflattert und zersplissen.
>
> Sein Antlitz ist zerfressen,
> Sein Auge ohne Glanz.
> Er hat vergessen
> Den eignen Namen ganz.
>
> Gleich einem alten Kind
> **(Gealtert früh in Harmen)**
> Steht er im Abendwind
> Und bettelt um Erbarmen.
>
> Es glänzt sein blondes Haar,
> Der Sonne doch ein Teilchen.
> Er bietet lächelnd dar
> Ein welkes Herz und welke Veilchen.

Was bedeutet 'Harmen'? Ist es eine Stadt, eine Organisation oder etwas anderes. Leider geben weder das Wörterbuch noch Google eine klare Antwort.
Ich entschuldige mich für mögliche Fehler: meine zweite Sprache ist Englisch.

Comment: Grimm's deutsches Wörterbuch kennt das Verb "harmen" (auch: "harnen") für das Wasserlassen. Ich schreibe das nicht als Antwort, weil ich glaube, dass die Bedeutung nicht in den Kontext passt.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn Du englischsprachig bist, dann ist Dir *harm* ein Begriff (to do some harm, harmful, harmless).

Harm ist im Deutschen selten, aber in abgeleiteten Wörtern wie *harmlos* sehr präsent.

*Gealtert früh in Harmen* würde ich mit *Gealtert früh in Schmerzen* oder *Leiden* erklären, nicht unbedingt körperlichen Schmerzen.

Answer (score 3):

[English tranlsation below]

Es ist nicht ganz eindeutig. *Harmen* ist kein Wort, das zur Entstehungszeit des Gedichts üblich war.

Es ist der Teil einer Stadt, aber der Kontext des Gedichts schließt diese Interpretation aus.

Hier ist also dichterische Freiheit im Spiel. Die Interpretation, die mir am wahrscheinlichsten erscheint, ist dass *Harmen* hier die substantivierte Form eines Verbes *harmen* ("sich grämen") ist.

Im Gegenwartsdeutsch ist das Substantiv *Harm* ein veraltetes oder zumindest veraltendes Wort. (Die einzige mir noch bekannte Verwendung ist im Weihnachtslied *Leise rieselt der Schnee*.) Ansonsten ist es noch im Adjektiv *harmlos* ("unschädlich") präsent.

Das mittelhochdeutsche Verb *harmen* (alternative Form: *härmen*) ist im Gegenwartsdeutsch ausgestorben, aber noch [in den Partizipialadjektiven *verhärmt* ("ausgezehrt") und *abgehärmt* ("von Kummer und Sorge gezeichnet") präsent](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abgeh%C3%A4rmt).

Die Bedeutung von *Harm* und *harmen* passt gut in den Kontext des Gedichtes. Es ist also wahrscheinlich, dass Klabund hier ein altertümliches oder altertümelndes Wort entweder verwendet oder eingeführt hat. Hier eine altertümelnde Form im Rahmen der dichterischen Freiheit anzunehmen erscheint mir sehr plausibel. Die Reimform legt nahe, dass *Harmen* nicht nur wegen seiner semantischen Assoziationen, sondern auch wegen des Reims zu *Erbarmen* passend erschien. Auf der hermeneutischen Ebene widerspricht auch der Kontext des Gedichts der Deutung einer altertümelnden Sprachverwendung nicht.

Das Gedicht spielt ironisch mit einer Vertauschung von Krieg und Frieden, indem es als "Friede" bezeichnet, was sich als eine Beschreibung des Krieges herausstellt: "Der Friede stürzt ins Land"). Gleichzeitig wird in der zweiten Strophe deutlich, dass dieser Friede dem Frieden nicht mehr ähnlich sieht.

Das Gedicht weckt mit Form und Inhalt Assoziationen an Gedichte des Dreißigjährigen Krieges, etwa von Andreas Gryphius. Im Gedicht ist an anderer Stelle die Adjektivdeklination im Vers "Er trägt ein grau Gewand" altertümlich. Eine altertümelnde Sprachverwendung trägt dazu bei, dem Thema des Gedichts ("Der Friede") eine überzeitliche Bedeutung beizulegen und Assoziationen an den Kontext der deutschen Geschichte zu verstärken. Eine weitere Analyse des Werkkontextes von Klabund müsste erschließen, ob die altertümelnde Verwendung mit dem Stil des Autors harmoniert. Das zu leisten bin ich leider hier nicht im Stande, weil mir das Werk Klabunds im Großen und Ganzen unbekannt ist.

Für die grammatische Analyse ist festzuhalten, dass *unter* hier den Dativ verlangt, weil es hier soviel wie "unter dem Einfluss ...", "unter dem Eindruck von ..." bedeutet (wie etwa in *unter Schmerzen*). Es kommen damit folgende Formen in Betracht:

Es könnte sich um den Dativ Plural ode den Dativ Singular von *Harm* handeln, oder aber um den Dativ des substantivierten Verbes *harmen*.

Problematisch an der Interpretation von *Harmen* als Plural von *Harm* ist, dass *Harm* ein Singularetantum ist, ein Wort, dass keinen Plural hat.

Auch der Dativ Singular von *Harm* lautet im Gegenwartsdeutsch nicht *Harmen*, sondern *Harm*. Unter der Prämisse altertümelnder Sprachverwendung ist auch die Dativbildung im Mittelhochdeutschen zu betrachten: [Im Mittelhochdeutschen lautete der Dativ Singular von *harm* wohl *harme*](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=Lexer&lemid=H00670#0), [andererseits gibt es wohl auch einen Beleg, in dem der Dativ Singular *hermen* lautet](http://www.mhdwb-online.de/wb.php?buchstabe=H&portion=440&link_lid=68859000#68859000), sodass die Existenz eines Dativ Singular *harmen* im Mittelhochdeutschen zumindest nicht völlig auszuschließen ist.

Die Frage ist hier ja auch nicht so sehr, ob diese Formen im Mittelhochdeutschen existierten, sondern ob Klabund sie im Sinn gehabt haben könnte. Und dafür ist auch in Betracht zu ziehen, dass *Harmen* ein von Klabund selbst gebildete Dativ oder Pluralform sein könnte. Die Form wäre in diesem Fall zumindest ein regelrecht gebildet.

Schließlich könnte es sich auch um den Dativ Singular des substantivierten Verbes *harmen* handeln.

Die Interpretation von *Harmen* als Dativ Singular des substantivierten Verbs *harmen* ist in meinen Augen wahrscheinlichste Interpretation, weil sie mir am prämissenärmsten erscheint. Die grammatische Mehrdeutigkeit lässt sich aber nicht vollständig auflösen.

Unabhängig von der Frage, um welche grammatische Form es sich handelt, ist die Bedeutung, dass der Frieden unter Sorgen und Nöten ausgezehrt und alt geworden ist.

---

It is somewhat ambiguous. When the poem was written, *Harmen* was not a common word.

*Harmen* is a part of the town Haslach, but the context of the poem rules out that interpretation.

The use of the word *Harmen* is "poetic freedom". The interpretation most probable to me is that *Harmen* is the substantivized form of a verb *harmen* ("to grieve", "to feel sorrow and pain").

In recent German, the noun *Harm* ("sorrow") is outdated or at least becoming outdated. The only use of it that I know is in the christmas song *Leise rieselt der Schnee*. Besides that, it is still present in the word *harmlos* ("harmless").

The middle high German verb *hamen* (alternative form: *härmen*) does not exist any more in recent German, but it is still present in the participle adjectives *verhärmt* ("haggard") and *abgehärmt* ("careworn").

The semantics of *Harm* and *harmen* fit the context of the poem. It seems probable, that Klabund used or introduced an antiquated or antiquarianising word. The rhyme form of the poet suggests that *Harmen* was chosen not just because of semantic association, but alsoe because of the rhyme with *Erbarmen*. The context of the poem does not provide a contradiction to that interpretation:

The poet plays with the confusion of war and peace in an ironic and critical manner. It names as *Friede* ("peace") what it otherwise unmasks as war. For instance the verb *ins Land fallen* ("to invade the country") is a verb used only to describe war. The whole second stanza makes clear that it is war that is being talked about.

In style, tone and topic, the poem arouses associations to German poems from the period of Thirty Years' War, for instance poems by Andreas Gryphius. In another verse of the poem ("Er trägt ein grau Gewand"), the declination of the adjective is antiquated as well. Antiquising use of language contributes to a time transcending meaning of the poem and strengthens associations to the German history. As the poem speaks of the aged peace, this harmonizes with the content of the poem. A further analysis of the works of Klabund would have to investigate whether this antiquising use of language would contradict the style of the author. This work is out of scope for me here, because I am not familiar with the oeuvre of Klabund.

For the grammatical analysis, it is important to recognize, that *Harmen* must be a form in dative case here, because the preposition *unter* is used in a way (meaning "under the influence of ..." or "under the impression of ...") demanding dative here (similar as in *unter Schmerzen* or *unter Drogen*). That is why the following grammatical forms have to be considered:

*Harmen* could be a dative plural of *Harm* or a dative singular of *Harm*. It could also be the dative of the substantivized verb *harmen*.

Interpreting *Harmen* as plural form of *Harm* is problematic, because *Harm* has no plural form in German.

Assuming the dative singular form of *Harm* is possible, but not straight-forward: The dative singular of *Harm* is *Harm* in recent German. But as we are operating on the premise of antiquated use of language, we should also take the Middle High German noun *harm* and its declination into account: It is not clear, what the dative singular of *harm* was in Middle High German. I found in a dictionary that it is *harme*, but there also seems to be an ocurrence of *hermen* as dative form. So, the possibility that there was a dative singular form *harmen* cannot totally be ruled out. The relevant question here is not so much, whether it actually existed. It is more relevant, whether Klabund could have had something like this in mind. And this seems be possible, as both the plural form and the dative would be in accordance with the way a group of nouns is actually delined (compare: *der Mensch*, *dem Menschen* [dative singular], *den Menschen* [dativ plural]).

Finally, it could be the dative of the substantivized verb *harmen*. To me, this appears to be the most probable interpretation, because it comes with the least amount of premises.

But it is impossible to fully resolve the grammatical ambiguity.

Regardless of the gramatical form, the meaning is in any case, that peace got old and careworn under the influence of sorrows and grieve.